# How can I compile the C interface LAPACKE using cmake and MinGW under Windows?

Tags: c, cmake, mingw, lapacke

I know there is binary released for Windows, I just want to try to compile it myself.
I got CMake, mingw32-make, gcc, gfortran and so on properly installed. (Using MinGW)

I tried

```
cd lapack
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
mingw32-make
```

Then I got the static library liblapack.a and libblas.a for Fortran, but no liblapacke.a (the C interface of lapack).

Is there a easy solution?

Comment: I've got this, for shared libraries use cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/i/want/to/install -DLAPACKE=ON -DCBLAS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON, while for static libraries just remove the -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON.

Answer (score 0):

LAPACKE is a collection of headers, there is nothing to be build. Link your program with the libraries you got (`liblapack` and `libblas`).

Comment: Thanks, but there is a liblapacke.dll file in the compiled version of Windows I downloaded, and the headers hints me to compile with -llapacke, which succeed. So what is that liblapacke.dll/.a? My program is written in C programming language.